# Page Alignment Issue on Second Page, and Additional Questions

Tags: formatting, packages, positioning, mactex

I am new to LaTeX, and could use some help.  I am currently using the following preamble in my document.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\author{Author}
\title{\textbf{Title of Document}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\setSingleSpace{1.1}
\SingleSpacing
\usepackage{xcolor,calc, blindtext}
\definecolor{chaptercolor}{gray}{0.8}
% helper macros
\newcommand\numlifter[1]{\raisebox{-2cm}[0pt][0pt]{\smash{#1}}}
\newcommand\numindent{\kern37pt}
\newlength\chaptertitleboxheight
\makechapterstyle{hansen}{
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{%
    \begingroup%
    \leavevmode%
    \chapnumfont%
    \strut%
    \numlifter{\thechapter}%
    \numindent%
\endgroup%
}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \vphantom{\begingroup%
      \leavevmode%
      \chapnumfont%
      \numlifter{\vphantom{9}}%
      \numindent%
      \endgroup}
    \afterchapternum}
  \setlength\midchapskip{0pt}
  \setlength\beforechapskip{0.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{%
    \fontsize{4cm}{0cm}%
    \bfseries%
    \sffamily%
    \color{chaptercolor}%
  }
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{%
    \normalfont%
    \huge%
    \bfseries%
    \raggedleft%
  }%
  \settototalheight\chaptertitleboxheight{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\chaptitlefont \strut bg\\bg\strut}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \parbox[t][\chaptertitleboxheight][t]{\textwidth}{%
      %\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}% add this if you use microtype
      \chaptitlefont\strut ##1\strut}%
}}
\chapterstyle{hansen}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\chapter{Preliminaries}
\blindtext

\blindtext 

\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

This works totally fine for the first page of the document (after the title page), but once I move to the next page (either by \newpage or just by exceeding the first page in terms of character count), the entire alignment of the page shifts to the right and aligns with the page number instead, which doesn't look like the first page.  I tried seeing what exactly was the issue in my code but I couldn't see anything that would do this in the preamble.

Also, it appears that the text in the top right hand corner is in all capitals.  It outputs "CHAPTER 1: PRELIMINARIES", but I would prefer for this to not be in all capitals and output "Chapter 1. Preliminaries".  Is there any way that I could do this while maintaining the formatting I currently have?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try the document option oneside.

Comment: Ulrike: Yes, this fixed the paragraph alignment issue, thank you! Is there any way to make "CHAPTER 1: PRELIMINARIES" output to "Chapter 1. Preliminaries", though?

Comment: Sure, memoir has lots of options.  Check the documentation.

Comment: note the different alignment for two side is by design, not a problem, open almost any book and the left (outer) margin of a left page will match the right (outer) margin of a right page

Comment: A quick solution to the second problem (uppercase in headers) is to insert `\nouppercaseheads` somewhere in the preamble.